# ‘gcroot’ attribute directive ignored

Tags: llvm-gcc

I get this warning when compiling:

```
main.c:20:12: warning: ‘gcroot’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
     struct C __attribute__((gcroot)) *garbage = new_C(0);
```

Is this attribute no longer supported?